# How to rewind stdin after reaching EOF?

Tags: c

I want to write a program that counts the frequency of all characters in stdin. My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 1024

int main()
{
    char c1, c2;
    int count[MAX], i = 0, unique = 1;
    char arr[MAX];

    c1 = fgetc(stdin); 
    while(c1  != EOF)
    {
        unsigned counter = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            if(c1 == arr[j])
            {
                unique = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(unique)
            arr[i] = c1;

        ungetc(c1, stdin); 
        c2 = fgetc(stdin); // a
        while (c2 != EOF)
        {
            if(arr[i] == c2)
            {
                counter++; // 2
                c2 = fgetc(stdin); //\n
            }
            else if(arr[i] != c2 && c2 != EOF)
            {
                //ungetc(c2, stdin);
                c2 = fgetc(stdin); // a EOF
            }
        }
        count[i] = counter;
        rewind(stdin);
        printf("%c: %d\n", arr[i], count[i]);
        c1 = fgetc(stdin); // a
        i++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

For the input: `anna` the output is: `a: 2`, so it counts all appearances for the 1st character but then EOF is reached, and I can't count any of the other characters. `rewind(stdin)` doesn't seem the work. What can I do?

Comment: Keep track of all characters (assuming ASCII) in an array of 255 unsigned ints, read through the stream, print them at the end.

Comment: `char c1, c2;` -> `int c1, c2;` - EOF is not a character and `fgetc` returns an int for this reason

Comment: `rewind(stdin)` will work just fine if `stdin` is a regular file.  However, if stdin is not a regular file, it will usually fail.  If you're running the program with `stdin` coming from the tty, `rewind` will fail.  Just put your input in a file and run the program with input redirected from the file.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Although actually the OP should then probably make their program work explicitly on files.

Comment: @WilliamPursell While your comment isn't wrong, it also doesn't help OP especially if they don't want to buffer their input into a file...

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica `stdin` is a file, and filters like this absolutely should read from `stdin`.  If `rewind` is necessary (it certainly isn't in this case!), the program should just abort with an error if rewind fails.  In that sense, it is designed to only work with regular files.  But there's no need to add any logic other than an error check on `rewind`.  Perhaps do a `stat` check early on an abort before doing any processing, but certainly do not add `-i` flags or require names as arguments.

Comment: This is a good point in your life to start reading manual pages and checking return values. For example, https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fseek.3.html states that a rewind() return value of ESPIPE indicates that the underlying device is not seekable.

Comment: @AKX Perhaps, but perhaps the underlying point is that the OP clearly does want to put the input in a file, but isn't aware of that.  Really, what the OP wants is to modify the algorithm so the `rewind` isn't necessary, but getting the current solution with the `rewind` to work is a good learning experience, IMO.

Comment: @WilliamPursell It is, I suppose, a matter of philosophy. I'm all for universal applicability and programs that are agnostic of the underlying medium until they can't be. I squarely expect that I can write through a pipe to a program that reads from stdin.

Comment: @WilliamPursell OP _wants_ to count occurrences of characters in a stream, and that absolutely doesn't need rewinding.

Comment: @AKX Yeah well, we have two distinct questions here: How to count characters in a stream, and how to rewind general streams (which only occurred as a side-effect of the OP's inefficient approach and thus is quite separate from the algorithmic problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't rewind a piped stream (such as stdin when it is e.g. redirected into your program or being entered on the keyboard) since there is no "tape of characters" to rewind, it's just a stream with no "memory" of what was entered before.

As elucidated in the comments, if you do redirect in a file (`./myapp < data.txt`), it can be rewound just fine.

However, you don't need to rewind the file to count the characters in it. As I commented,

> Keep track of all characters (assuming ASCII) in an array of 256 unsigned ints, read through the stream, print them at the end.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int c;
  unsigned int counts[256] = {0};

  while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF) {
    counts[c]++;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    if (counts[i]) {
      printf("%c: %d\n", i, counts[i]);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

As other commenters mention, you also need to use an `int`, not a `char`, for the retval of `fgetc()`, since EOF is -1.